# Some but not all custom CSS is overriding Bootstrap 4 settings

Tags: html, css, button, bootstrap-4

Forgive my ignorance on this but I'm a total noob and don't really know what I'm doing!

I've put together a basic webpage (http://dcbproductions.co.uk/) using Bootstrap 4 and want to modify some of the colours and design to fit my branding.  For the most part this has worked, but I'm struggling with a button.  I've managed to change the colour of the text on the button in default state and in hover.  However, I'm trying to change the background colour in both states too, but nothing is happening.  Here is the code I'm using:

```
.btn-light {
  background-color: #fcf8d7 !important;
  background-image: none !important;
  text-shadow: none;
  color: #714c82;
}

.btn-light:hover{
  background-color: #714c82;
  background-image: none;);
  color: #939393;
  text-shadow: none;
}
```

And within my page's html file I've got:

```
<a href="mailto:..." <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-lg"><i class="far fa-envelope"></i> Email Us</button></a>
```

Also, for some reason, this code doesn't even change the text colour when in my CSS file online.  It only works when I add it within  tags in my html, even though when working on the site offline it works fine when in the CSS.

I hope this all makes sense.

Does anyone have any ideas what's causing me problems?

Comment: you should add important for after your style

Comment: NO!... you should be **removing** any `!important` statements. The CSS cascade should take care of this assuming you are loading your CSS files in teh right order.

Comment: as above, never use !important.  The only time i can think to use it is; if theres an inline style that you cannot remove for some reason (ie, a third party is placing it there).   CSS Specificity and cascading should take care of your need to use important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should remove `important` as it is not required, there is syntax error as well in your code like `background-image: none;);`

```
.btn-light {
    background-color: #fcf8d7;
    background-image: none;
    text-shadow: none;
    color: #714c82;
}
.btn-light:hover {
    background-color: #714c82;
    background-image: none;
    color: #939393;
    text-shadow: none;
}
```

on hover of button this is how it will look
[image]

also there is syntax error in below line

`<a href="mailto:..." <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-lg"><i class="far fa-envelope"></i> Email Us</button></a>`

this should be

`<a href="mailto:dave@dcbproductions.co.uk" class="btn btn-light btn-lg"><i class="far fa-envelope"></i> Email Us</a>`

Comment: That worked, thank you!  I'd spotted that CSS error before but I must have accidentally brought it back when undoing changes I'd made.  I'm not sure why my html was so off though.  I got it from the Bootstrap site I think, but mustn't have been using it the right context.

Comment: I'm still having the problem where my custom CSS isn't fully working though.  I had to add the .btn-light code as a <style> element in my page's html.  Any ideas why that happened?  I've got my stylesheet added after the Bootstrap one on my page.  That's the right way around isn't it?

Comment: in home.cs file look for `.btn-light` and remove `important` from there it will work

Comment: you dont need to add that code in `style` tag, you can put that code in end of `home.css` file as well, just try it should work

Comment: It is in home.css but doesn't work when only there for some reason.  It only works online when I add it to the style tags on home.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't use !important as mentioned in an comment above.  You need to look into CSS specificity.

Every selector has its place in the specificity hierarchy. There are four categories which define the specificity level of a selector:

- Inline styles - An inline style is attached directly to the element
  to be styled. Example: .
- IDs - An ID is a unique identifier for the page elements, such as
  #navbar.
- Classes, attributes and pseudo-classes - This category includes
  .classes, [attributes] and pseudo-classes such as :hover, :focus etc.
- Elements and pseudo-elements - This category includes element names
  and pseudo-elements, such as h1, div, :before and :after.

To override styles you need to make your css more specific. You can do this in many ways but the simplest might be to just prepend the element type to the style.  For example your style would be something like:

```
button.btn-light {
  background-color: #fcf8d7;
  background-image: none;
  text-shadow: none;
  color: #714c82;
}

button.btn-light:hover{
  background-color: #714c82;
  background-image: none;
  color: #939393;
  text-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: That didn't work at all.  I lost all the customisation on the button after prepending 'button' to the element type as you'd written.  I changed it to btn.btn-light, which brought back my text colour customisation, but it still didn't affect the background.